# .NET Mocking framework for medical devices

Tags: .net, mocking, medical

Does anyone have experience in using a .NET mocking framework for medical device software?

I'm currently considering both Moq and Rhino Mocks and was hoping for some insight on their usage under FDA and EU requirements and possibly some resources on validation performed for either of them.

Thanks!

Comment: is are you expecting an mock of a device sending/receiving HL7 over MLLP?

Comment: @p.campbell: We're utilizing an in-house protocol and while the mocking library will certainly be required to mock communication messages and responses between the application under test and the hardware, it will be used for non-hardware related mocking too.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get any mocking framework validated for FDA? We're facing similar issue...

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your question, and assuming you are developing a "regulated medical device" that requires (see FDA guidance and engage experts to assist you in determining if applies to you) COTS/tool validation, you already know "The bottom line is that all third party tools (and libraries) used to construct or test FDA regulated software need to be validated.".

Reference http://rdn-consulting.com/blog/2011/11/12/validation-of-off-the-shelf-software-development-tools/

Your use of mocking framework could possibly fall into the above or may fall into "tool validation".

The best answer you could probably hope for here would be a response from someone who has done such COTS or "tool validation" for a similar mocking framework.  They may be able to provide "some advise", but it is not likely you will get their COTS/tool validation plan and documented validation results.

Best advise is probably to review FDA guidance and if necessary develop a COTS/tool validation plan like you are already doing for your other development tools such as compilers, SCM, and so on.